# Anyone care to help optimize a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

Here's the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS c, MAX(`followers_count`) AS max_fc, 
       MIN(`followers_count`) AS min_fc, MAX(`following_count`) AS max_fgc,
       MIN(`following_count`) AS min_fgc, SUM(`followers_count`) AS fc,
       SUM(`following_count`) AS fgc, MAX(`updates_count`) AS max_uc,
       MIN(`updates_count`) AS min_uc, SUM(`updates_count`) AS uc
FROM `profiles`
WHERE `twitter_id` IN (SELECT `followed_by` 
                       FROM `relations` 
                       WHERE `twitter_id` = 123);
```

The two tables are `profiles` and `relations`. Both have over 1,000,000 rows, InnoDB engine. Both have indexes on `twitter_id`, `relations` has an extra index on (`twitter_id`, `followed_by`). The query is taking over 6 seconds to execute, this really frustrates me. I know that I can JOIN this somehow, but my MySQL knowledge is not so cool, that's why I'm asking for your help.

Thanks in advance everyone =)

Cheers,
K ~

**Updated**

Okay I managed to get down to 2,5 seconds. I used INNER JOIN and added the three index pairs. Here's the EXPLAIN results:

```
id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, 
    key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra

1, 'SIMPLE', 'r', 'ref', 'relation', 
    'relation', '4', 'const', 252310, 'Using index'

1, 'SIMPLE', 'p', 'ref', 'PRIMARY,twiter_id,id_fc,id_fgc,id_uc', 
    'id_uc', '4', 'follerme.r.followed_by', 1, ''
```

Hope this helps.

**Another update**

Here are the SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for both tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `profiles` (
  `twitter_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `screen_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `followers_count` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `following_count` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `updates_count` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `location` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `bio` varchar(160) default NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `registered` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `timestamp` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `relations_timestamp` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  USING BTREE (`twitter_id`,`screen_name`),
  KEY `twiter_id` (`twitter_id`),
  KEY `screen_name` USING BTREE (`screen_name`,`twitter_id`),
  KEY `id_fc` (`twitter_id`,`followers_count`),
  KEY `id_fgc` (`twitter_id`,`following_count`),
  KEY `id_uc` (`twitter_id`,`updates_count`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `relations` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `twitter_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `followed_by` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `timestamp` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  USING BTREE (`id`,`twitter_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `relation` (`twitter_id`,`followed_by`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1209557 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Wow, what a mess =) Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the following composite indexes:

```
profiles (twitter_id, followers_count)
profiles (twitter_id, following_count)
profiles (twitter_id, updates_count)
```

and post the query plan, for God's sake.

By the way, how many rows does this `COUNT(*)` return?

**Update:**

Your table rows are quite long. Create a composite index on all the fields you select:

```
profiles (twitter_id, followers_count, following_count, updates_count)
```

so that the `JOIN` query can retrieve all the values it need from that index.

Comment: Thanks! Created the index pairs, id_fc, id_fgc, id_uc. Seems to have spared me ~300 ms. Query plan? You mean the EXPLAIN results? Look at the qestion update.

Comment: COUNT(*) returns 195436 rows. Got some errors there, unknown column p.twitter_id in the where clause (for all of them I guess). After I added p to every FROM profiles it said Unknown column 'r.followed_by' in 'on clause'. Not sure what to do next.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @kovshenin: as for the error, well, 3 seconds is quite a decent time for 200,000 rows. Could you please post complete `CREATE TABLE` statements for you `profiles` and `relations`?

Comment: Hey, fixed the previous errors. Sorry didn't figure it out myself. Anyways, now I'm stuck with this one: Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause. Shoud I group anything?

Comment: Updated my post with the `CREATE TABLE` statements. 3 seconds is decent, but not enough and I know there is a way to go below that and it's only a matter of time before I find out, haha =) Although it may take me two or three months to read that MySQL High Performance book I bought a few weeks ago. =))

Comment: @kovshenin: ummm... sorry, I didn't get your logic right. Forget the last query :) Just post your table definitions if you please.

Comment: Hey, thanks for all your help buddy, I'm down to ~2 seconds =)

Answer (score 3):

A join would look something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS c,
MAX(p.`followers_count`) AS max_fc,
MIN(p.`followers_count`) AS min_fc,
MAX(p.`following_count`) AS max_fgc,
MIN(p.`following_count`) AS min_fgc,
SUM(p.`followers_count`) AS fc,
SUM(p.`following_count`) AS fgc,
MAX(p.`updates_count`) AS max_uc,
MIN(p.`updates_count`) AS min_uc,
SUM(p.`updates_count`) AS uc
FROM `profiles` AS p
INNER JOIN `relations` AS r ON p.`twitter_id` = r.`followed_by`
WHERE r.`twitter_id` = 123;
```

To help optimize it you should run EXPLAIN SELECT ... on both queries.

Comment: A join would slow this way down.

Comment: This decreased the execution time from 6s to 3s

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS c,
  MAX(`followers_count`) AS max_fc, MIN(`followers_count`) AS min_fc,
  MAX(`following_count`) AS max_fgc, MIN(`following_count`) AS min_fgc,
  SUM(`followers_count`) AS fc, SUM(`following_count`) AS fgc,
  MAX(`updates_count`) AS max_uc, MIN(`updates_count`) AS min_uc, SUM(`updates_count`) AS uc
FROM `profiles`
JOIN `relations`
  ON (profiles.twitter_id = relations.followed_by)
WHERE relations.twitted_id = 123;
```

might be a bit faster, but you'll need to measure and check if that is indeed so.

Comment: I went with the above method, but I think there's no difference in these two.

Comment: Yep, the differences in how/if you break the lines, or table aliases and field qualifications, don't matter (except you'd need to use aliases and/or qualifications if needed to disambiguate, but I see no trace of that here).

Answer (score 1):

**count(*)** is a very expensive operation under the InnoDB Engine, have you tried this query without that piece?  If it's causing the most processing time then maybe you could keep a running value instead of querying for it each time.

Comment: That only really applies when there's no WHERE

Comment: Hmm, hadn't heard that before but guess it makes sense.

Comment: Removing COUNT(*) didn't change anything :(

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach this problem from a programmers angle; I'd have a separate table (or storage area somewhere) that stored the max,min and sum values associated with each field in your original query and update those values every time I updated and added a table record. (although deleting may be problematic if not handled correctly).

After the original query to populate these values is complete (which is the almost the same as the query you posted), you're essentially reducing your final query to getting one row from a data table, rather than computing everything all at once.

Comment: same as gandolfs idea above really!

Comment: You mean like having TRIGGERS update those values every time? Hmm, might be a good idea.

Comment: Yup, its been a while since I've used mySQL, wern't sure if they had triggers or not, but yes thats the general idea :)